# How to create Google's +1 rolling animation using JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When you click the +1 button below a post on Google+, the counter on the right increments, but it does so with a rolling animation, kinda like old odometers:

[image: Observe the rolling animation on the right]

How can I create such an effect, using Javascript?

Comment: Well, what have you tried?

Comment: It's not actually rolling.  The 2 is moving up and the 3 is moving up underneath it.  Thinking about it like this should help you find a solution.

Comment: You could use http://api.jquery.com/animate/ for the top or bottom property and overflow: hidden on the parent element. If you allready using jquery.ui you should take a look at this: http://api.jqueryui.com/1.9/slide-effect/

Comment: @DylanCross Well, I tried to inspect this with Safari's developer tools, but animation like that are tricky, and it seems like Google is creating DOM elements on-the-fly. I was hoping to understand it, more than to re-implement it.

Comment: @Danwilliger So, I guess you're saying it's two integers on top of each other, with only the top one visible, and then animating both!?

Comment: Check out my answer below.  It's One number on top of another.  Animating them both vertically, then removing the top one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I've provided a solution.  Basically I'm appending a new number below the first one.  Animating them both up. Removing the first number.  Setting the second number to the right position.

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', 'button', function (evt) {
        var num, element, self;
        self = $(".number").first();
        num = parseInt($(".number:last").text());
        num = num + 1;
        element = '<div class="number">' + num.toString() + '</div>';
        $(".container").append(element);
        $(".number").animate(
            { top: "-=20" }, 
            150, 
            function () {
                self.remove();
                $(".number").css("top", "0px");
            }
        );
    });
});
```

This is the solution  http://jsfiddle.net/Dtwigs/KrpGp/

Comment: Thank you so much for this. That's a really clever and simple solution. I converted this to ES6.

Answer (score 2):

Here's something to get you started:

http://jsfiddle.net/XKmJf/

```
.wrapper {

    position:relative;

}

.wrapper .number-1 {

position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
    background-color:white;

}


<div class="wrapper">
    <a class="number-1">1</a>
    <a class="number-2">2</a>
</div>


$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".wrapper .number-1").animate({top:"-100px"}, 1000);

});
```